# What embedded HTTP server library options should I look at?

Tags: http, open-source

I'm looking to write a small proxy server for kicks and giggles.

Apart from the options in libWWW, can anyone recommend any opensource options for the HTTP server and client code? Thinking of a library of some kind similar to libWWW.

Chosen language is C/C++ but open to Java, C#, Python... etc. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose the Java way, take a look at **Jetty**. It's full featured HTTP server which is very easy to embed and pretty lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty is great indeed. However, if you want a proxy server, take a look at [RabbIT proxy.](http://khelekore.org/rabbit/) It is well designed and amenable to modifications. e.g. We implemented a filter that serialized certain XML text in requests to Java objects, and similarly deserialized responses.

There's a wide array of choices depending on what you want to do. For example, to handle NTLM authentication, you have cNTLM (C) or NTLMAPS (Python) or jCIFS library (Java).

Answer (score 0):

If you're considering to make your proxy server in Asynchronous way in C/C++.
Here's some of open source projects you might want to check out:

- libevent provides one - good choice for light use. but recursion on large data is not provided..
- [mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) - nice API, good abstraction, but it uses select() and realloc() based i/o buffer, Also dual license for commercial use.
- libevhtp - developed as a replacement of libevent's http module.
- GNU's libmicrohttpd - good feature set.
- [libasyncd](http://wolkykim.github.io/libasyncd/) - I'm the author. It features general asynchronous framework and comes with HTTP handler.

I'm only able to make 2 links on my answer, but you can easily find the project homes by googling them.